# Is there a faster way to add dates up to a certain future date using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to speed this up if possible,

First I search for a given date and if that date does not exist, then it adds the whole year to the sheet by copying the previous formulas.

Can some of you experts take a look please.

```vb
Sub addyear()
    'check to see if there is a year in the list
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim Place As String

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aNumber As Long
    Dim ColsCount As Long
    Dim counting As Long
    counting = 0
    Dim rowNum As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ColsCount = Sheet11.Cells(2, Sheet11.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    aNumber = Sheet11.Range("B9").Value

    Set rng = Sheet11.Range("2:2")

    rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
        MsgBox "Year Exists"
    Else
        aNumber = Sheet11.Range("A9").Value

        Set rng = Sheet11.Range("2:2")

        rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
        
        If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
            MsgBox "Year Exists"
        Else
            Do Until Not IsError(rowNum)
                Sheet11.Cells(1, ColsCount).Copy Sheet11.Cells(1, ColsCount + 1)
                Sheet11.Cells(2, ColsCount).Copy Sheet11.Cells(2, ColsCount + 1)
                Sheet11.Cells(3, ColsCount).Copy Sheet11.Cells(3, ColsCount + 1)
        
                ColsCount = ColsCount + 1
                counting = counting + 1
                If counting > 366 Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Exit Sub
        
                aNumber = Sheet11.Range("A9").Value

                Set rng = Sheet11.Range("2:2")

                rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
            Loop
            If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
                MsgBox "year Entered"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you like to finally accomplish? Do you search for a date on the second row. If the date is found, nothing to be done. If not, some other date must be placed on the row 2. If my above understanding is correct, can you specify what are you trying to to after? Should you place the first of January on the first cell of the second row, and the row in discussion should be filled with all the next year date? Is is something correct from my above assumption? If not, please try better explaining (in works) what you try to accomplish...

Comment: i am trying to search for a date on the second row, if that date does not exist, e.g 01/01/2021 then that whole year is to be added to the end of the 2nd row as the previous year will exist. my code works but is very slow because of the loop adding each date after the next. thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: So, the new year will be added after the existing year, not overwriting the existing range. Correct? If yes, I will prepare a much simpler and faster code, which should do the job almost instantly...

Comment: thanks that sounds good, but it still has to have the line above and below the same

Comment: Nothing (else) will be changed... In one minute you will have the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testMatchDate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, searchD As Long, matchNo As Long, lastCol As Long, NoDays As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastCol = sh.cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last filled column
  searchD = CDate("01.01.2021")                    'the date of the next year first day
  NoDays = 61                                      'Number of days to be filled
  matchNo = Application.Match(searchD, sh.Rows(2)) 'find its position (if exists..)

  If matchNo > 0 And matchNo < lastCol Then
    MsgBox "The new year date exists..."
    Exit Sub                                       'exiting if it exists
  ElseIf matchNo = lastCol Then 'if Match does not find a match, it returns the last filled column number...
    If CDate(searchD) = CDate(sh.cells(2, lastCol).Value) Then
        MsgBox "The new year date exists..."
        Exit Sub                                   'exiting if it exists
    End If
  End If

  sh.cells(2, lastCol + 1).Value = CDate(searchD) 'Write the first date of the new year
  sh.cells(2, lastCol + 2).Formula = "=" & sh.cells(2, lastCol + 1).Address(0, 0) & " + 1" 'and formula
  'autofill NoDays:
  sh.cells(2, lastCol + 2).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range(cells(2, lastCol + 2), sh.cells(2, lastCol + NoDays))
End Sub
```

Adapted the code to also receive the number of days to be filled. But, in such a variant, your data to be searched must be the first one to be filled. I can adapt it to search for a specific date, but to not fill starting from it, to fill starting from existing date. Should I prepare the code to work in this way? If I will not receive an answer in a reasonable period of time, I can do it only after 2 - 3 hours when I will be at home...

Comment: thanks for the code, ive added a missing end if and the speed is great. one thing though. the previous date may not be the last date of the previous year so adding +365 will add more than required. thanks again though

Comment: @Moss Lovell: Please, refresh the page (this one) and copy the last code... So, **how much is required**? I mean, how many days? A month, two...? We can set the amount like a variable. The updated code uses, anyhow such a variable, calculating the Leap Year number of days...

Comment: the chances are it will be the whole year but if not could you work out the amount of days between the last date and the 31/12/?? as it doesnt matter if leap year or not as the last day will always be 31st December

Comment: It will no matter for a human being, but VBA must know how many cells to AutoFill... But what you are saying now is not the same with the initial question. So, you do not want to fill the next year, do you want to fill the actual year up to its end? Can you better explain what you need? In about fifteen minutes I must leave the office...

Comment: I thank you for your time i will work out some code to work out how many to auto fill. i know you are a busy person and your time and effort is appreciated.

Comment: @Moss Lovell: I will adapt the code to fill whatever you need, being necessary to also set a variable, named, let us say, `NoDays`...

Comment: @Moss Lovell: Adapted the above code to also receive the number of days to be filled. If you will decide that a specific number will be necessary, you will fill it and will let it untouched. It maybe will become a constant... **Is this approach convenient for you**? Then, would you like to let the inserted formulas on the worksheet, or to transform them in values? Using this method, no formulas are necessary and formulas increases the workbook size. I mean, in general...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220111/discussion-between-moss-lovell-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru Thank you once again, for your help.I have used a mix of both our codes and it now does what i want.

```
Sub addyear()
'check to see if there is a year in the list
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Place As String

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim dt1 As Date
Dim dt2 As Date
Dim nDays As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim aNumber As Long
Dim ColsCount As Long
Dim counting As Long
counting = 0
Dim rowNum As Variant
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ColsCount = Sheet11.Cells(2, Sheet11.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

aNumber = Sheet11.Range("B9").Value

Set rng = Sheet11.Range("2:2")

rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)


If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
    MsgBox "Year Exists"
Else

aNumber = Sheet11.Range("b9").Value

Set rng = Sheet11.Range("2:2")

rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)


If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
    MsgBox "Year Exists"
    
Else

 dt1 = Sheet11.Cells(2, ColsCount).Value
dt2 = Sheet11.Range("b9")
nDays = DateDiff("d", dt1, dt2)

sh.Cells(2, ColsCount + 1).Formula = "=" & sh.Cells(2, ColsCount).Address(0, 0) & " + 1"
sh.Cells(3, ColsCount + 1).Formula = "=" & sh.Cells(3, ColsCount).Address(0, 0) & " + 1"
sh.Cells(1, ColsCount + 1).Formula = "=" & sh.Cells(1, ColsCount).Address(0, 0) & " + 1"

sh.Cells(3, ColsCount + 1).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range(Cells(3, ColsCount + 1), sh.Cells(3, ColsCount + nDays))
sh.Cells(2, ColsCount + 1).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range(Cells(2, ColsCount + 1), sh.Cells(2, ColsCount + nDays))
sh.Cells(1, ColsCount + 1).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range(Cells(1, ColsCount + 1), sh.Cells(1, ColsCount + nDays))

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "year Entered"
    
End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: would be nice to have the code added so that the formatting of the added cells match the previous ones :)